# Qt: How to find text, while the criteria is in a QStringList?

Tags: qt, ubuntu

I load a file with QTextStream, then read it line by line with readLine. Then I want to get the line which have some keywords. Then, I remove the keywords from each line, so I will get entire line minus the keywords.

I wonder if the keywords can be stored in a QStringList so I can do looping to find them. Or any other simpler way to do it?

To be clear, I want to get some data from APT cache file of Ubuntu. Similar like this:

```
Package: flashplugin-downloader
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/web
Installed-Size: 41
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Bart Martens <bartm@knars.be>
Architecture: i386
Source: flashplugin-nonfree
Version: 11.2.202.359ubuntu0.12.04.1
Depends: flashplugin-installer (>= 11.1.102.55ubuntu3)
Filename: pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/flashplugin-downloader_11.2.202.359ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
Size: 1832
Homepage: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html
Description-md5: 66ea91f4e504085408ea841953dc65d0
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu

Package: flashplugin-installer
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/web
Installed-Size: 137
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Bart Martens <bartm@knars.be>
Architecture: i386
Source: flashplugin-nonfree
Version: 11.2.202.359ubuntu0.12.04.1
Replaces: flashplugin (<< 6), flashplugin-downloader (<< 11.1.102.55ubuntu3), flashplugin-nonfree (<< 11.0.1.152ubuntu1)
Provides: flashplugin-nonfree
Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0, wget, libgtk2.0-0, fontconfig, libxt6, libxext6, libatk1.0-0, libc6, libcairo2, libexpat1, libfontconfig1, libfreetype6, libglib2.0-0, libice6, libpango1.0-0, libpng12-0, libsm6, libx11-6, libxau6, libxcursor1, libxdmcp6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxinerama1, libxrandr2, libxrender1, zlib1g, libnss3-1d, libnspr4-0d, libcurl3 | libcurl3-gnutls, libasound2, update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2)
Recommends: libasound2-plugins (>= 1.0.16)
Suggests: firefox, x-ttcidfont-conf, ttf-mscorefonts-installer, ttf-bitstream-vera | ttf-dejavu, ttf-xfree86-nonfree, xfs
Conflicts: flashplayer-mozilla, flashplugin (<< 6), flashplugin-nonfree (<< 11.0.1.152ubuntu1), libflashsupport
Breaks: flashplugin-downloader (<< 11.1.102.55ubuntu3)
Filename: pool/multiverse/f/flashplugin-nonfree/flashplugin-installer_11.2.202.359ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb
Size: 7014
Homepage: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html
Description-md5: a03e9ebc20ce82c05567d088e79bf750
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
```

I want to get lines which contains Package, Size, Filename, and Description from above file.

I don't get a proper keyword to ask Google.

**EDIT:**
So far, my approach is like this:

```
if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    QTextStream text(&file);
    while(!text.atEnd())
    {
        QString line = text.readLine();
        foreach(QString key, criteria) //criteria is a QStringList
        {
            if(line.contains(criteria))
            {
                qDebug() << line.remove(criteria);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The files to be read might have size up to 25 MB. I wonder if above code can be effective. Maybe you can teach me how to use QVector or else.

Comment: Side note: make sure that you set up the locale for any application that you subsequently parse the human-readable output from. This output may well be localized.

Comment: Only you can answer the question whether your code is "effective". If you don't have measurements to show how long it takes, and for what output, you can't even begin to improve anything since you won't know if there's an improvement, and by how much. And - most of all - if it's at all necessary. So, essentially, at this point there's nothing we can help you with.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll try to improve it by myself then. But, sorry, I don't understand what to be localized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you think using shell script would be better of in this case.
All you need to do is call `cat <filename> | grep -e Package -e Size -e Filename -e Description`. Use a QProcess and read the output stream. You could change the shell script call to only get the fields (lines) that you require, And instead of hardcoded values use regex.

I still don't know what are you trying to achieve. And why are you using QT to achieve the task.
Maybe some more information regarding what are you trying to achieve will give a better idea of the problem in hand. And its corresponding solution.

Comment: I only know bash command a little bit, but I'll try your suggestion.  And, what I want to actually achieve is to convert APT cache into a database, maybe SQLite. And I only need some pieces of the data from it.

Comment: Then you could convert the file into a CSV format with the data you want using a shell command (I think writing QT code would be overkill. It would require lots of coding, while with shell script it would be just 2-3 lines of code max). And then use the SQLite CSV import facility. Hope that helps.